# Filter objects with many-to-many table in Rails using has_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-scope

There are two tables: User and Industry. User can relate to many industries and a lot of users belong to one Industry.

Industry.rb

```
class Industry <ApplicationRecord
    has_many: users,: through =>: industry_users
    has_many: industry_users
end
```

User.rb

```
class User <ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to: specialty
  has_many: industries,: through =>: industry_users
  has_many: industry_users

  scope: by_specialty, -> specialty {where (: specialty_id => specialty)}
  scope: by_period, -> started_at, ended_at {where ("graduation_date> =? AND graduation_date <=?", started_at, ended_at)}
end
```

IndustryUser.rb

The relationship between them is many_to_many.
There is a third table IndustryUser which stores two columns.

```
class IndustryUser <ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to: user
    belongs_to: industry
end
```

Now I'm developing an API. I use has_scope gem to filter users by parameters in get request. Above, I successfully filtered them on the specialty and the date of graduation.
For example, filtering on the specialty.

```
http://localhost:3000/v1/users?by_specialty=1
```

Filtering by the date of graduation. You should provide period of time.

```
http://localhost:3000/v1/users?
by_period[started_at]=20040101&by_period[ended_at]=20070101
```

I got stuck when I wanted to get users who belong to a particular industry.
Here is an example of a get query

```
http://localhost:3000/v1/users?by_industry=2
```

For example. Here, I want it to render all users who are related to the second industry.
Does anyone know how to filter objects that relate to many-to-many relations using has_scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* it's going to be something like:

```
scope: by_industry, -> industry {User.joins(:industry_users).where(industry_users: {id: IndustryUser.where(industry: Industry.where(id: industry))})}
```

This bit finds the correct industry:

```
Industry.where(id: industry)
```

This bit finds `IndustryUser` records that reference the just-found `Industry`:

```
IndustryUser.where(industry: Industry.where(id: industry))
```

And then you join on the found `industry_users` to find `User`s that are reference by the `industry_users`.

```
User.joins(:industry_users).where(industry_users: {id: IndustryUser.where(industry: Industry.where(id: industry))})
```

Comment: I put scope which you suggested me. There is an error.

Comment: "#<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near``

Comment: I wrote last command in rails console and there is above error.

Comment: The error appeared because there is no primary key in IndustryUser. I added column id as primary key. and now it works. Thank you